# How to modify attributes of the Wagtail form input fields?

Tags: django, django-forms, wagtail

I'm looking at `wagtail` *hello-world* [form](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/contrib/forms/index.html)
 example:

```
class FormField(AbstractFormField):
    page = ParentalKey('FormPage', related_name='form_fields')


class FormPage(AbstractEmailForm):
    landing_page_template = 'blog/form_page.html'
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    thank_you_text = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
        FormSubmissionsPanel(),
        FieldPanel('intro', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('form_fields', label="Form fields"),
        FieldPanel('thank_you_text', classname="full"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldRowPanel([
                FieldPanel('from_address', classname="col6"),
                FieldPanel('to_address', classname="col6"),
            ]),
            FieldPanel('subject'),
        ], "Email"),
    ]
```

If given the template like this:

```
{% for field in form %}
  {{ field }} 
{% endfor %}
```

It will render HTML similar to the following:

```
<input type="text" name="label1" value="Default Label1" required maxlength="255" id="id_label1" />
<input type="url" name="label2" value="http://Label2.net" id="id_label2" />
<textarea name="label3" required rows="10" id="id_label3" cols="40">
```

How can I modify/add extra attributes to the rendered input fields?

For instance:

- How to add `class="form-control"`?
- How to change `rows="5"` in the `textarea` input?

Is there any other convenient way apart from javascript madness?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you are wanting to change how `FormPage`'s  are rendered (ie. pages that extend `AbstractEmailForm` or `AbstractForm`).

There are some ways to do this from within your `form_page.html` template (see links at bottom of answer), however, I think your best bet is to add these attributes before they get to the template.

This way you can keep your template really simple, even just using a copy and paste from the [docs example](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/contrib/forms/index.html).

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
        {{ page.intro|richtext }}
        <form action="{% pageurl page %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, in `my_app/models.py` you want to override the `get_form` method on your `FormPage`. You can see what the `get_form` method does in the Wagtail [form/models.py code](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/stable/1.13.x/wagtail/wagtailforms/models.py#L204-L207).

You need to ensure that you are getting the generated `form` object via super. Then iterate through the fields - updating the widget on each field. Widgets are used to render the input field (or Textarea) and by default the [Textarea widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#textarea) contains 10 rows and 40 cols.

You an also update the `attrs` dictionary on any widget with the `class` key to add custom classes to the rendered input. This way we can add `form-control` to every single input.

See example:

```
from django.forms import widgets  # used to find TextArea widget
# other imports.... AbstractEmailForm etc

class FormPage(AbstractEmailForm):
    # body, thank_you_text, etc

    def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(*args, **kwargs)
        # form = super(AbstractEmailForm, self).get_form(*args, **kwargs)  # use this syntax for Python 2.x
        # iterate through the fields in the generated form
        for name, field in form.fields.items():
            # here we want to adjust the widgets on each field
            # if the field is a TextArea - adjust the rows
            if isinstance(field.widget, widgets.Textarea):
                field.widget.attrs.update({'rows': '5'})
            # for all fields, get any existing CSS classes and add 'form-control'
            # ensure the 'class' attribute is a string of classes with spaces
            css_classes = field.widget.attrs.get('class', '').split()
            css_classes.append('form-control')
            field.widget.attrs.update({'class': ' '.join(css_classes)})
        return form
```

This will render **all** textarea inputs with `rows=5` in the html attributes and also add `form-control` to the `class` attributes of all inputs (even hidden inputs if used). Remember that this will change every single `FormPage` in use.

For more complex rendering of forms within the template, this article is really good but it gets pretty full on:  https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html#accessing-the-form-fields-individually

Also, for basic Bootstrap 3 (or 4) rendering of forms, [Crispy Forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) may save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: Brilliant! 2 years later and this helped boost my ego to a coworker.  Thank you.  I modified this to add a placeholder text to each form field.  I'm using the help text in my case because we do not use it in this particular project. field.widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': field.help_text})

Comment: Awesome to hear.

Answer (score 3):

You can create dynamic templates:
Create a loop through `form`
 [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#looping-over-hidden-and-visible-fields)

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
   <div>
      <div class="form-group mb-10">
         {{ field.errors }}
         {{ field.label_tag }}
         <input type="{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}" class="form-control"
                name="{{ field.name }}" id="{{ field.id_for_label }}"
                {% if field.field.required %}required="required"{% endif %}>
         {% comment %}you might want form field for textarea or select etc. just make conditions for those {% endcomment %}
      </div>
  </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a `widget` argument to `FieldPanel`, to define the [Django widget object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/) to use with that field. Amongst other things, this allows you to customise the HTML attributes that appear on the field:

```
from django import forms

class FormPage(AbstractEmailForm):
    content_panels = [
        # ...
        FieldPanel('subject', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension of the answer provided by w411-3 ...

If you want to keep all this within the template, and have a multi-line **textarea** you can take advantage of the **{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}** which supplies a **True** for all but the **textarea** field.

```
<form action="{% pageurl page %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <div class="form-group mb-10">
        {{ field.errors }}
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>

        {% if field.field.widget.input_type %}

        <input type="{% if field.field.widget.input_type == 'number' %}
                          tel
                     {% else %}
                          {{ field.field.widget.input_type }}
                     {% endif %}" 
            class="form-control" 
            name="{{ field.name }}"
            id="{{ field.id_for_label }}"
            placeholder="{{ field.help_text }}"
            {% if field.field.required %}required="required"{% endif %}>

        {% else %}

        <textarea type="{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}" 
            class="form-control" 
            name="{{ field.name }}"
            id="{{ field.id_for_label }}"
            placeholder="{{ field.help_text }}"
            {% if field.field.required %}required="required"{% endif %}
            ></textarea>

        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

You could replace the html **label** definition with : {{ field.label_tag }}, however this method allows you to easily add extra css classes if needed.

The **if** statement within the **input type** removes the arrow / spinners that are automatically added to number fields.  For some reason Wagtail does not provide the telephone data type in forms which would make this unnecessary.

Note: If you want custom elements for each form type, look at the Wagtail Documentation on [Rendering Templates for StreamFields](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/topics/streamfield.html#template-rendering).  Instead of **if block.block_type == 'heading'** you could use something similar to **field.field.widget.input_type == 'number'** and perhaps create a more elegant solution.

This source is now available as a [Wagtail app on GitHub.](https://github.com/chandra-kumala-school/contact)